# HTTP range requests not working on IIS Express static resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, curl, iis-express

I am working on a solution to stream mp4 files on Safari from Asp.Net MVC using the .net framework. Safari requires the use of HTTP range requests to play video files.

As far as I researched, IIS and IIS Express support range requests for static files natively, but Asp.Net MVC requires some "magic" I intend to work on.

So far I have created a small proof of concept application that returns the MP4 FileStream from a Controller, and I also have a copy of the MP4 file available as a static file, under the /Contents folder.

I created the HTTP range requests using curl and Fiddler Composer, and I had the same unexpected results in both.

Requests to both URLs, the MVC endpoint and the static file resource, return HTTP response 200 and the entire file in the response content. I was expecting 200 for the MVC endpoint and 206 with a partial result for the static file.

I don't know if I am testing it wrongly, or if I am missing some configuration, either on IIS or on my Asp.Net MVC application.

This is my curl request:

`curl https://localhost:44381/Content/PERCE%20ROCK2.mp4 -i -H "Range: bytes=0-1023" --insecure -o /dev/null`

And this is the result:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3275k  100 3275k    0     0  47.7M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48.4M
```

I was expecting the request to return 1KB (0-1023) but it returned the entire file (3.2 MB).

This is the code that returns the mp4 video using the controller, and it is working as expected:

```
    public class VideoController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        // GET video/getfile
        public ActionResult GetFile()
        {
            var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\code\poc\RangeRequestPoc\RangeRequestPoc\obj\Debug\PERCE ROCK2.mp4");
            return File(fileStream, "video/mp4");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code "that returns the MP4 FileStream from a Controller".

Comment: I edited the question and added the Controller code, but that one is working as expected. I understand the static file served from the Asp.Net `Content` folder should be served with support for range requests, and it is not. I am not sure I can make a custom request handler support range requests in IIS if that feature, that should be supported out of the box, is not working.